# Compass Can't Find Sprite Folder

Tags: compass-sass

For some reason Compass can not find this folder I setup for sprites. This is what my directories look like.

```
Project
   media
      compass
         sass
            modules
               _module.scss
            style.scss
         config.rb
      images
         sprites
             button_hover.jpg
             button_active.jpg
             button.jpg
```

And inside of my config.rb file I have the images_dir setup to be ../images.  The errors I get when I try import ( `@import '../images/sprites/button*.jpg'`) the files inside of the _module.scss are mainly this:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: images/sprites/button*.jpg.
```

Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 11):

Compass sprites are PNG only. No JPG afaik.

Answer (score 2):

Well if **styles.scss** is in *media/compass/sass* and **images** is in *media/* then you need to do `../../` instead of `../` no ?

Comment: It depends. In this case `I have the images_dir setup to be ../images`, so actually he should be just saying `sprites/button*.jpg`. (But Josef Richter is correct that Compass won't do jpg sprites :( )

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with compass 0.12.2 in windows *using png files* and solved it by editing `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\compass-0.12.2\lib\compass\sprite_importer.rb`

Change line 19:

```
-      Dir.glob(File.join(path, "**", glob))
+      Sass::Util.glob(File.join(path, "**", glob))
```

And line 78:

```
-        files = Dir[File.join(folder, uri)].sort
+        files = Sass::Util.glob(File.join(folder, uri)).sort
```

All according to this source:
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/commit/58babac01b56eddf63bac737f7f781d98f00f6b9

Answer (score 0):

configure your config.rb. then compass will know where to find your images ;)

and compass seems to work with png's only.